# Logging only insert, update and delete mysql queries

Tags: mysql, logging

I'm using a WAMP server with phpmyadmin and MySQL 5.0. I've been looking for a way to only log all insert, update and delete queries, to no avail though.

I did manage to get it to auto generate logs adding the "log=C:\wamp\mysql\log\queries.log" line to the my.ini configuration file of mysql, but the log didn't log the exact queries.

What i'm trying is that, whenever an insert, delete or update query happens, it logs the query in a file or in another table. Is this possible with procedures? What are my choices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is achieved through the Binary Log . You enable it using the *log-bin* parameter.
You can read the contents of a binary log using this utility, the mysqlbinlog .

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. Other than the mysqlbinlog, are there other ways to read the log file? Like, Java can write/read binary files, will it read the log properly as well?

Comment: I gueess you can, but mysqlbinlog has many parsing features, such as <a href="http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html#option_mysqlbinlog_start-datetime" target="_blank">start-datetime</a> which lets you select the starting date & time of statements to display.

Comment: I personally found the output of `mysqlbinlog` hard to read. Reading the general log was much more helpful, after filtering out `SELECT` queries.

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround. You can pass the `tail`'s output to `grep`, e.g. like this:

```sh
tail -f /var/log/mysql/mysql.log | grep "update "
```

Comment: This only works if the general log has been enabled, right?